# Dúvida sobre Categorias/Páginas PHP ou HTML!

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, estou criando um site e não estou usando o WordPress porque não é um blog, e gostaria de uma ajuda, na verdade tirar uma dúvida, tem como fazer categorias sem ser por pastas? tipo você cria uma pasta no www com nome "vídeos" e nela coloca index.php essas coisas, tem como fazer isso no PHP? sem precisar criar pasta e aparecer os vídeos lá na hora que entrar na categoria, acho que minha dúvida não está compreensiva caso alguém não entenda eu irei reformular.

Comment: Acho que o que você quer é reescrita de URL. Pesquise sobre isso.

Comment: Não Anderson, eu gostaria de saber como fazer uma categoria usando PHP sem precisar usar pastas.

Comment: Com a reescrita você consegue fazer isso. Você pode criar um arquivo `videos.php` e fazer com que uma URL `localhost/videos` execute esse arquivo.

Comment: ha tá, vou ver se eu acho algo relacionado a isso, obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado Anderson era isso mesmo, valeu cara, pode responder para eu marcar como resolvido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas detalhando o que foi dito pelo Anderson, voce pode usar a reescrita de URL.

--

O .htaccess (o nome do arquivo é escrito desta maneira mesmo, com um ponto na frente) é um arquivo especial utilizado pelo Apache (servidor web) que verifica se há alguma restrição ou configuração especial para o diretório acessado. É com ele que iremos ativar a reescrita de URL e configurar outros parâmetros necessários.

Crie o arquivo .htaccess, insira o contúdo abaixo e salve o mesmo na pasta raiz do seu projeto (a mesma onde se encontra seu index.php).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

A primeira linha habilita a reescrita.

A segunda e terceira linha dizem para o Apache ignorar a reescrita caso o endereço se referir a um arquivo ("f" de file) ou pasta ("d" de directory).

A quarta linha indica ao Apache qual a regra de reescrita será aplicada. Ela basicamente captura tudo o que vier depois de index.php e retorna como parâmetro para a página. Não vou me extender muito nos detalhes desta configuração, mas caso você queira saber mais a respeiro, indico ver a documentação do mod_rewrite do Apache.

Existêm algumas variações desta configuração, mas esta é a que uso.

OBS: Lembre-se também de habilitar o mod_rewrite do Apache e reiniciá-lo. Caso não saiba como fazer pesquise no Google de acordo com seu sistema operacional.

--

Dá uma olhada neste blog:
http://www.sergiotoledo.com.br/tutoriais/php/reescrita-de-url